# Are selection and projection associative?

Tags: database, relational-algebra

Is selection(p)(projection(R)) == projection(selection(p)(R)) always?

Comment: do you need kind of proof for it?

Comment: @csviri: I don't need a proof. I just want to know for what cases it holds and what cases it doesn't.

Comment: The google friendly way to formulate this question is: "Can projection be pushed through selection" (and vice versa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If think if the selection is on subset of columns that are used in projections then YES,

but if not, there can be a situation where you are making a selection on columns that not exists.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for this conjecture.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any reference litrature. But if you think about it, we can separate only for these 2 cases, if the precondition holds ( selection is on subset of columns that are used in projections) this is trivial case since a projection defines a relation with only a subset of columns. If not holds and you are making a selection on a  not existing column if wrong, this cannot be done.
So its not always commutative, just if the mentioned precondition holds.

Answer (score 3):

First, the property of 'commutativity' simply doesn't apply to your case.

Commutativity is the property that for all x,y : x op y == y op x.

For example, for all R1,R2 : R1 NATURAL JOIN R2 == R2 NATURAL JOIN R1.

Second, the answer is no.

A projection can only be moved inside a restrict if the projection retains all the attributes that are involved in the restriction condition. Otherwise, the overall expression simply becomes invalid.

EDIT

(With a bit of a stretch, you could argue that commutativity is involved because your example case is about the question of whether FUNCTION COMPOSITION is commutative (f°g ?= g°f).  Knowing your maths should make your question a rhetorical one, in that case, however.)

EDIT 2

And changing the question to whether they are associative is no good either.  Associativity is a case with one single operator and three arguments, where the question is whether (a op b) op c ?= a op (b op c), for all a,b,c.  You have two operators (projection and selection) and one single argument.

That also means that the question of DISTRIBUTIVITY (in its strict mathematical sense) does not apply either, although your scenario does resemble the mathematical case of operator distributivity, in certain respects, and given enough stretch.  Distributivity in its strict mathematical sense involves two *dyadic* operators (i.e. taking two arguments).  Projection and restriction are unary.

I think csviri has answered your question proper.  You should accept it.